# PHP doesn't return json decode

Tags: php, json

I have been trying to fetch some data from steam API which returns JSON such as this:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$2.76","volume":"345","median_price":"$2.60"}
```

However it does not return anything to the variable which is used somewhere else. It just shows 0.

Here's my JSON code, what am I doing wrong?

```
$steam1 = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%20Case%20Key";
$json = file_get_contents($steam1);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$median1= $json_data["median_price"];
$media1 = $median1 / '2.49';
```

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Why would you think dividing by a string would be a good idea?

Comment: The price begins with `$` so it can't be parsed as a number. You need to remove the `$` first.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with `json_decode`? Did you try `var_dump($json_data)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_decode()` is working fine. The problem is that you can't do arithmetic when a number begins with `$`.

You need to remove the `$` character at the beginning of the price before you can use it as a number. Otherwise, it will be converted to `0`.

```
$median1 = ltrim($json_data["median_price"], '$');
$media1 = $median1 / 2.49;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. Will mark as correct as soon as Im allowed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dollar in the `$json_data["median_price"]` so that must be removed before you can use the field in any arithmetic.

Also you need to use a number as a divisor and not a string.

This works

```
<?php
$steam1 = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%20Case%20Key";
$json = file_get_contents($steam1);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$median1= $json_data["median_price"];
$median1 = substr($median1,0,1) == '$' ? substr($median1,1) : $median1;  //remove the $
$media1 = $median1 / 2.49;
echo $media1;
```

Answer (score 1):

=)) I hope you joke!

```
// It's ok:
$steam1 = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%20Case%20Key";
$json = file_get_contents($steam1);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

// here you set $median1 = "$2.60", yeah, it's string (not float number)
$median1= $json_data["median_price"];

// here you trying to divide one string to another
$media1 = $median1 / '2.49';
```

It's very interesting way )))

Change last string to:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+))/', $median1, $matches)) {
    $media1 = round($matches[1] / 2.49, 2);
} else {
    $media1 = 0;
}
echo $media1 . "\n";
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow, Big hammer - Little nut

Comment: I don't know the site steamcommunity.com, but if there are all prices in $, you can use `ltrim($median1, '$') / 2.49`. In my version scripts try to find any int or float value from string `$median1`.

Comment: I was not complaining. Looks bullet proof